# need to convert SQL CROSS JOIN into LINQ

Tags: join

I have two tables table1 and table2. Each table contains a column with itemPrice. I need to add the two columns together.

The SQL query below returns the correct SUM.

```
 SELECT SUM(item1+ item2) FROM 
(select SUM(t1.itemPrice) item1 from table1 t1 WHERE t1.userid=='jonh') tableA
CROSS JOIN
(select SUM(t2.itemPrice) item2 from table2 t2 WHERE t1.userid=='jonh') tableB
```

I am not been lazy but the above query has so many SUM functions that I don't know where to start to write LINQ queries.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ceci,

Hopefully this will give you what you want...

```
from f in   (    
    from x in   (   from t1 in Table1 
                    where  t1.Userid.Equals("John") 
                    select new { Userid = t1.Userid }
                ).Distinct() 
    select new {    item1 = (   from z in Table1 
                                where z.Userid.Equals("John") 
                                select z.ItemPrice ).Sum() ??0 ,
                    item2 = (   from z in Table2 
                                where z.Userid.Equals("John") 
                                select z.ItemPrice ).Sum() ??0 } 
            ) select new { total = f.item1 + f.item2 }
```

In the case where there are no records for "john" in one table, it will bring back a 0 and sum up the other tables.

hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome it works great! I would've never got this to work on my own.  Thank you. 

Quick question. There must be a shorter way to write this, no? Its seems long.

Comment: @ceci, I am not a LINQ expert, maybe someone with more experience can come up with a more concise solution.

Comment: Ed, you have added this "??0" in the query and I would assume it returns zero if its empty.  I tried googling but can't find anything. Can you explain what its used for? thanks.

Comment: You want the sum of the ItemPrice for both TableA & TableB, but if you didn't have rows in TableA for 'john', but had rows in TableB for him, your results would be null. The ?? 0 says that if Null return 0. So now you will get valid results even if only one table contained rows for 'John'. This is a common problem in Linq handling Nulls. this URL will give you info... https://www.google.com/search?q=linq+sum+null+return+zero&oq=Linq+sum+null&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.12486j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=linq+sum+null+return+zero